# Sqlite manager's icon doesn't appear

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have downloaded the Sqlite's jar file, placed it in the right folder and restarted eclipse but didn't find the icon that should have appeared. Where can I find it?

[The steps I was following.](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

Comment: In the DDMS perspective, File Explorer tab. Select a db file and click on the icon.

Comment: Yes, until you don't select a file... Select a db and it will light up in color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the DDMS perspective, in the File Explorer tab.

It will be disabled until you don't select a file.
Select a db and the icon will light up in color.

You're now ready to explore your db.